# Can xmr.to work without javascript?

Tags: mymonero, bitcoin, xmr.to

I found on reddit a post that was created one year ago. And there are links to xmr.to and xmr tor address and there types it work without javascript. But today I went to xmr.to and it said you need to turn on javascript to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

The frontend has been updated recently and does not redirect to the no-javascript version automatically if you have javascript disabled. This is clearly a mistake and should be fixed soon.

For the time being you can access explicitly the no-javascript version at https://xmr.to/nojs

Note that if you access it on its onion address at http://xmrto2bturnore26.onion you will also get the no-javascript version.